# How to read property of undefined object from MongoDB aggregation?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I am building a Treasure Hunt webapp using NodeJS/ExpressJS and MongoDB which comprises of two teams and users. Each user have individual score which add to team score. I want to display Total Score of both team on the dashboard view. I used MongoDB's Aggregation framework to query the db. Here is the code which works fine and returns an array of objects.

```
module.exports.getTotalTeamScore = function () {
   User.aggregate([
        { $group: {
            _id: "$team",
            total: { $sum: "$score"}
        }}
    ], function (err, results) {
        if (err) {
            console.error(err);
        } else {
            console.log(results);
            return results;
        }
    }
   );
}
```

I made this function in User model file. Now when I call this function from some route file by

`var teamsObj = User.getTotalTeamScore();`,

it does gives the array of objects as following however it is undefined.

```
[ { _id: 'Team Black', total: 40 },
{ _id: 'Team Red', total: 60 } ]
```

The problem is that I am unable to do something like this in route file. (I can access it fine inside the User model file where `getTotalTeamScore` function exists):

```
teamsObj[0].total
```

The error I get is `TypeError: Cannot read property 'total' of undefined`.

Please help me solve this problem. I am still new to NodeJS/ExpressJS & MongoDB and want to learn.

Thank you

Comment: tell me how you are calling this function getTotalTeamScore from other route file. Paste your code. There is problem in your getTotalTeamScore, the way it returns results.

Comment: added to the original question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function `getTotalTeamScore` is executing mongodb aggregate function which is async operation.

So it will not return result immediately, but your function will be retured before aggregations returns DB records. 
So you need to use callback.

First Modify your `getTotalTeamScore` function like this:

```
module.exports.getTotalTeamScore = function (callback) {
   User.aggregate([
        { $group: {
            _id: "$team",
            total: { $sum: "$score"}
        }}
    ], function (err, results) {
        if (err) {
            callback(err);
            console.error(err);

        } else {
            console.log(results);
            callback(null, results);
        }
    }
   );
}
```

And then call like this:

```
User.getTotalTeamScore(function (err, records) {
    if (err) {
        // Handle Error
    } else {
       teamsObj = records; 
       // Further Processing.
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Your solution is 100% correct and fixed the issue.